# urllib.quote_plus doesn't encode plus

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, urlencode, url-encoding

Here's what I'm doing:

```
from urllib import quote_plus
email = quote_plus('name+other@gmail.com')
```

but

```
print email
> name+other%40gmail.com
```

so if I put it in a URL the `+` becomes a space when I pull it out. But I want it to stay a plus. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's `name%2Bother%40gmail.com` for me (*Python2.7.14* on *Win*).

Comment: @wogsland Is that the snippet which is reproducible ? Cannot reproduce it to..

Answer (score 0):

Try to define `safe` parameter explicitly, like in the code below:

```
from urllib import quote_plus

email = quote_plus('name+other@gmail.com', safe='/')
print email
```

If that works the reason I can assume is that the source code of the `urllib.quote_plus` has been modified somehow...